# Adding SQLite to Windows 10 Universal app VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, sqlite, win-universal-app

I am trying to add local database functionality to app Universal Windows 10 app. I've been told the simplest method is using SQLite.

I followed the tutorial up at: http://igrali.com/2015/05/01/using-sqlite-in-windows-10-universal-apps/ although it was in C# I did think this would be an issue to translate.

I installed the VS2015 Add-on, have the reference set, but cannot create a database at all!

Does anyone know how to set up the project correctly and create a database to work with in VB?

Below is an example. I have SQL.Net.Attributes imported, but it wont recognise [Primary Key]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Basic, an attribute is enclosed in angle brackets (<>). You can find more information here :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx

Comment: It recognises Primary Key + Auto-increment however it flags an error stating that these attributes cannot be applied to this type

Answer (score 0):

I now have a working example. I used SQLiteStudio to create a Database and used the SQLite-PCL library to create a connection for CRUD operations